# Fusing arrows sideways in mermaid diagrams

Tags: r, diagram, mermaid

How can I add laterally fused arrows in a R sequential mermaid diagram?
In the the example below:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("
graph TB
    A[GE Solution]-->C{1:1}
    B[GA Solution]-->C{1:1} 
    C{1:1}-->D[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]
    D[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]-->E[Homogenisation at 10000 r/min]
    ")
```

How could I produce sth like the following?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played around with `mermaid` and I'm not sure there is functionality for that, it looks like it was meant to be a simple solution for documentation, not one with lots of flexibility. You can do the same diagram however with graphViz:

```
library(DiagrammeR)

grViz("digraph dot {
    node [shape=rectange];

    d1 [shape=point,width=0.01,height=0.01];
    {'GE Solution', 'GA Solution'}->d1[dir=none];
    d1->'Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min';
    'Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min'->'Homogenisation at 10000 r/min'}")
```

[image]

**Edit to respond to comment**: Use a subgraph and rank an invisible dot (`d2` in this example) and the the node you wish to have it level with as the same (here `40oC`).

```
grViz("digraph dot {
node [shape=rectange];

d1 [shape=point,width=0.01,height=0.01];
d2 [shape=point, width=0.01, height=0.01];
{'GE Solution', 'GA Solution'}->d1[dir=none];
d1->'Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min';
'Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min'->d2[dir=none];
subgraph {
    rank=same;
    d2; '40oC';
}
d2->'40oC'[dir=none];
d2->'Homogenisation at 10000 r/min'}")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Originally I was eager to find a solution in Mermaid as it feels much easier to write. Still, concerning the side item on "40oC" which is obliquely connected to the arrow, would you also know how to implement that, please?

Comment: i added an edit to my answer responding to your question but the solution is to use a subgraph

Comment: very nice: I think you can get away without the subgraph just using `{ rank=same;  d2 -> '40oC'[dir=none] };`

Answer (score 15):

A possible solution in mermaid;

```
graph LR
   X --- D[ ]:::empty
   Y --- D
   D --> E
   classDef empty width:0px,height:0px;
```

[image: Mermaid diagram with merging sideway connectors]

Comment: If you want to make it a bit more concise, you could also write: `X & Y --- D[ ]:::empty --> E`

Comment: The class empty is a very good idea. Can style also accomodate relative position from other elements?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work anymore: there is a blank spot at the place there the arrows meet.

Comment: ```mermaid
graph LR
   X & Y --- D( ):::empty
   D --> E
   classDef empty width:-1px,height:-1px;

```

At least makes a little circle at the node - which ... IMO looks slightly better than the empty place.

https://gist.github.com/chrismo/deccb12b9220a5ac357f64ceeb6ac54a/93f71466ba41cd395565b2cfe460efac4630be84

Comment: When I used `classDef empty width:0px,height:0px;` I ended up with a gap between the arrows. However if I use `style D width:0;` that was enough. Docs: [Styling a node](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html?id=flowcharts-basic-syntax#styling-a-node)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solutions to @Paulo's answer:

Based on your image I think this looks the best:

```
---
config:
  flowchart: 
    curve: linear
---
flowchart TD
   A[GE Solution] --- recEmpty[ ]:::empty
   B[GA Solution] --- recEmpty
   recEmpty --> C[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]
   classDef empty width:0px
```

[image]

Other examples:

```
flowchart-elk TD
   A[GE Solution] --- recEmpty[ ]:::empty
   B[GA Solution] --- recEmpty
   recEmpty --> C[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]
   classDef empty width:0px
```

[image]

```
flowchart TD
   A[GE Solution] --- recEmpty[ ]:::empty
   B[GA Solution] --- recEmpty
   recEmpty --> C[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]
   classDef empty width:0px
```

[image]

```
---
config:
  flowchart: 
    curve: stepAfter
  
---
flowchart TD
   A[GE Solution] --- recEmpty[ ]:::empty
   B[GA Solution] --- recEmpty
   recEmpty --> C[Stir 10 mins at 500 r/min]
   classDef empty width:0px
```

[image]